how do I display an image in an Excel cell based on the selection the user has made in the dropdown of another cell?
Microsoft Excel.
How do I display an image in an Excel cell based on the user's selection in the dropdown of another cell?
The code below stops at the second last line:
imageData = imagePath.Picture
with the message 'invalid qualifier'.
I am sure I have specified the correct worksheet and cell reference which contain the image. I don't know if the surrounding syntax is correct.
Sub ShowImageBasedOnDropdown()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dropdownValue As String
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim pic As Picture
    
    ' Set the worksheet where the dropdown and target cell are located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("purchasessheet")
    
    ' Get the value from the dropdown (for example, E2)
    dropdownValue = ws.Range("E2").Value
    
    ' Clear any existing pictures in the target cell (for example, D2)
    For Each pic In ws.Pictures
        If Not Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, ws.Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then
            pic.Delete
        End If
    Next pic
    
    ' Select the image path based on the dropdown value
    Select Case dropdownValue
        Case "Corn"
            imagePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("lookupsheet").Range("J2")
        Case "Rice bran"
            imagePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("lookupsheet").Range("J3")
        Case "Eggstock"
            imagePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("lookupsheet").Range("J4")
        ' Add more cases for other dropdown values as needed
    End Select
    
    imageData = imagePath.Picture

    Range("purchasessheet!D2").Picture = imageData
End Sub



Range("purchasessheet!D2").Picture = imageData


Range.Picture is not a valid property or method of the Excel Range object.
Dynamic pictures is generally done without the use of VBA.  The trick is to have a Shape's formula = to a defined name that returns a range based on a formula that returns a range.

AwayBanner =OFFSET(INDEX(NFLTeams,MATCH(
AwayTeamChoose,NFLTeams,0)),0,-1,1,2) AwayTeamChoose =Settings!$B$12
GameTime =Settings!$B$15 HomeBanner =OFFSET(INDEX(NFLTeams,MATCH(
HomeTeamChoose,NFLTeams,0)),0,-1,1,2) HomeTeamChoose =Settings!$B$11
NFLTeams ='NFL Teams'!$B$2:$B$33


Watch: How to display images dynamically in Excel

The solution I have used could not be simpler. No VBA.
=XLOOKUP(E3, lookupsheet!$R$2:$R$4, lookupsheet!$S$2:$S$4)


Here is a new trick that I didn't know about: How to Use Excel's NEW Lookup of Images  Professional Dashboards Just Got Easy ➕ Bonus Reveal

If you have access to the new IMAGE function - Microsoft Support, you could try this:

Define a table with names to show in drop-down and along with paths, tbImage in this example
Create a name for lookup based on table (cannot use tables directly yet), imageNames = =tbImage[Name]
Select cells for drop-downs and set the list as imageNames
In the first cell, enter this dynamic array formula formula

=LET(
    selection, A7:A8,
    IF(
        ISBLANK(selection),
        "",
        IMAGE(XLOOKUP(selection, tbImage[Name], tbImage[Path]), selection)
    )
)


